# JHipster page won't render properly

Tags: node.js, maven, jhipster

When I run the command mvn spring-boot:run, I get no errors. The problem is when I localhost:8080, the site does not properly render. I can not post an image here, but Home, Account, and Language are all in bullet form. Now when I installed it, I did get the error MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe" which I believe is related to node.js. I downloaded Visual Studio Express 2013, but I still get the error. Could these two be related?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues.
To resolve the issue, I had to recreate a new project and for the option to use the Compass CSS Authoring Framework, I chose "No".
That resolved it for me.